# search engine optimization / content listing/ url rewriting for dynamic website in php and mysql

Tags: php, url-rewriting, seo, search-engine

> Abstract: How to convert mydomain.com/viewTopic.php?id=xxxx to mydomain.com/xxxx

I am working on a knowledge sharing website where I have an admin panel to enter new topics and storing them in mysql DB(id,subject,content,tags).

I have page to view (viewTopic.php) each topics by providing the id as (mydomain.com/viewTopic.php?id=xx).

But if I have 2 topics say 'jQuery' and 'angularjs' I want them to be viewed as 'mydomain.com/jQuery' and 'mydomain.com/angularjs'.

Also I want these pages to be listed in search engines os if I use url rewriting in htaccess is it possible to list all entries in google?

Can anybody please help me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[^./]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1/ [R=301,L] 

RewriteRule (.*)/$ viewTopic.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Try the above .htaccess code. Your final URL will be example.com/xxxx/

Comment: Thank you. I got that. But is it possible with this approach to list each entry on a search engine?? Suppose some body searches for XXXX (assuming xxxx is a valid search query) is the page (mydomain.com/xxxx) going to be listed in the result

Comment: URL is one of many factors in SEO ranking pattern. Read more about SEO.